# Installed ubuntu on an external can't boot to windows without it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I was out of town visiting a friend and I installed ubuntu to an external and gave it to him when I left. Got home realized windows won't boot without the hard drive. Can this be fixed without reinstalling windows.  It goes to the grub rescue. only problem is the HDD it's looking for is a few hours away.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB was probably installed on the other HDD. To fix this your going to have to use a liveCD, either burned onto a USB or a disc.
Once your on a desktop run these commands in a terminal  to install boot-repair, A program meant to repair common GRUB issues.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Once installed type `boot-repair` and select the "recommended repair" option and attempt rebooting without the liveCD when it's finished.

That should fix it, If not report back here. Good luck!